# Multipart request return 415

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I want to implement endpoint for multipart request in my .net core 2.2 web app. Endpoint should receive model and image.

```
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(Model request, IFormFile file)
{
        // some action
}

public class Model
{
        public string FirstProperty { get; set; }

        public string SecondProperty { get; set; }
}
```

This endpoint always return 415 (Unsupported Media Type). I know about issue in .net core 2.2 (https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4396). Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: This is incomplete. Paste your HTML code as well.

Comment: Is it built on Asp Core Pages or MVC Handler?

Comment: @AshokanSivapragasam It is Web API

Comment: Make `IFormFile` file the property of your model class and mark `Model request` with attribute `[FromForm]`

Comment: @Dev123 my pleasure! I have added this as an answer - please feel free to mark as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `IFormFile file` the property of your model class and mark `Model request` with attribute `[FromForm]`.